# Issue with Github for windows and Custom Shell

Tags: windows, git, github-for-windows, console2

I'm having problems trying to set my Custom Shell in Github for windows to Console2.
It seems like no matter what I try it wants to ignore my setting and just launch in powershell.

Under Github for Windows I have the path for my custom shell set to where I have Console2 installed and the checkmark is next to Custom. (double and triple checked this for sanity)

I've tried restarting my computer multiple times, and even changing the setting to the other options (ie cmd and Git Bash).

In all 3 cases launching gitshell still launches Powershell instead.
I tried to search around here and google but haven't found anyone having a similar problem. Is there anywhere (ie registry or db file) where I could check to see how these values are set, and try to override it? Or if anyone else has experiences this problem and has a solution I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue as well. As a workaround, choosing "Open in Git Shell" in the gear menu of the GUI client is opening Git Bash (my shell of choice) in the repo I'm in, but this only allows one terminal window and isn't a true solution.

I'm guessing a bug was introduced in one of the recent Windows client updates. I'm going to let them know about it at https://github.com/contact and I suggest others do the same if they also have this issue.